# how to connect oracle database 10g with c# and the connection string must be in app.config?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, app-config

my app.config file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.16;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SP;Password=qfirst;Unicode=True"
        providerName="" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And i created a class file like below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WindowsApplication4
{
    class class1
    {
        string c = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(C);
        public void openconnection()
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("conn opened");
        }
    }
}
```

but when i run it , it shows an error message.Please Help me...

Comment: What is the error message _exactly_?

Comment: And move your connection string and `OracleConnection` definitions part in your method.

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact code you are trying to run but the above code would not compile because the string variable you're passing to the OracleConnection constructor is not defined. Try changing the argument to lowercase "c".

Comment: I changed it into lowercase but didn't run

Comment: want to know the coding of how to connect database in oracle